# Server ftp write errors

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, ftp, server

We have a linux based server through which we offer a hosting service. We have a problem  with WordPress and other platforms.   each  wordpress site asks FTP accounts every time you install WordPress, themes, add ons or to try to upgrade it .

We need to get write access to the wordpress , joomla , drupal , etc. platforms automatically when its installed to customers server space via softaculus .

I have no experience of the hosting service, im just make websites, and I've tried to make the ftp accounts wp -config file, but it does not fix the  other customer sites and when added to the wp -config file, it is not the best solution (Still asks for a password when install theme, add ons or update anything)

Sorry for bad english. can anyone help me to get this problem fixed?

We need write acces for: Joomla, Wordpress, Drupal, Magent ETC bases. We have c-panel acces for every customer and softaculus installer for wordpress etc platforms

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error message, web server needs to get write access to the WordPress files. So you can add write access to the files, I think the problem will resolved.

If you couldn't add write access to the files, you would contact your hosting service center.

Comment: But i am that service center :) 

There is problem with write acces, It needs to be automaticly. I dont know where config it?

Linux based server, C-Panel for every customer. 

Problem is when i try upload add on it ask ftp cresendials, I add ftp cresendials but it wont work (add on needs write acces. example .htacces file, I need manualy but few row of code to it, But it still not working probably) 

I need write acces automaticly for platforms

Comment: Oh, you are the service center! What is your owner name of the files? And what kind of web server do you use? (For example Apache or Nginx)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the permissions problems here.
You need to be sure that your webserver can read all files and folders in the web root folder and you need to make every user the owner of each folder and files.

Using cPanel it should be done automatically when you create FTP user and providing it's home directory. If you have a mess with permissions already you may need to edit them manually. You can try to set 644 permission for all files and folders and then change owner to the actual user.

Look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/these-key-elements-of-access-permissions-are-everything-to-your-linux-server-security.html) for more information about file permissions on Linux, it should help.

Answer (score -1):

Its been fixed, I set on apache write access different so its now working probably!

Link for details:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/folder-permission-on-linux-ubuntu